# Penetration rate for miniature cone

Tags: geotechnical-engineering, soil, soil-mechanics

Is there any recommended/suggested/required penetration rate for a miniature cone penetrometer? A 20mm/s is for a standard size of cone penetrometer, what about for miniature one?

Comment: I don't believe there is a non-standard cone penetrometer test acceptable to official standard soil tests.

Answer (score 0):

Miniature Cone Penetration (Mini-CPT) Test is a new type of CPT but in diameter less than conventional CPT to determine the bearing capacity and strength parameters of loose to semi-dense soils at shallow depth. Mini-CPT needs lower force to penetrate into the soil, and its ability to identify very thin underneath layers is higher than CPT.

Miniature cone penetrometers are available with the reduced cross-sectional sizes of 5 cm2 and 1 cm2 (Tumay et al., 1998).

In the referenced article, the ASTM-D3441 (2004) standard method was followed to perform the tests. Please read on to find information that interests you.

[Reference](https://geopersia.ut.ac.ir/article_29232_4396b231406b95427060cfbd200e6ed6.pdf)